# cmake .. does not find LLVMConfig.cmake

Tags: json, cmake

I found a tool to generate UML diagrams : https://github.com/bkryza/clang-uml

> For CMake projects, simply invoke the cmake command as cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ...

it requires to run

```
C:\Vs2022\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```

the idea is that it is supposed to generate a json file

```
clang-uml requires an up-to-date compile_commands.json file
```

but I get this error

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.20348.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29337.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29337.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Vs2019/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Vs2019/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
  the following names:

    LLVMConfig.cmake
    llvm-config.cmake
```

I found a file that resemble it, but I feel I am doing something wrong

- How can I generate that json file ?

thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the project was missing.
After having installed the correct version of LLVM (older version than the one installed), I could make it work.

Details: a build script was supposed to run and clone the llvm repo/building it. This is what happens when you pickup a project with no handover

Comment: what part was missing? what was the correct version you needed to install? [WHO ARE YOU DENVERCODER9](https://xkcd.com/979/)?

Comment: a build script was supposed to run and clone the llvm repo/building it, I dont really have time to dig that out, one can maybe discard this question, it is more related to internal repository handling where I work. not always easy to take formers employee repo's without any handover

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the details.  The point of the query was to make your answer better.

Comment: done, I wont add more details as per company policies

Answer (score 0):

When building LLVM from source, I've found that using the Ninja generator gets LLVM to install `LLVMConfig.cmake`.
You'll need to install [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) and add it to your `PATH` first.
Here's the steps I used to build and install LLVM 17.0.3 and add it to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git llvm
cd llvm
git switch -c llvmorg-17.0.3 llvmorg-17.0.3
cmake -GNinja -S llvm -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Program Files/LLVM"
cmake --build build
cmake --build build --target install
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH', [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH') + ';C:\Program Files\LLVM', 'User')
```

Open a new terminal to get the updated `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable.